# Node module cloudfront-log-parser not parsing correctly AWS CloudFront logs

Tags: node.js, amazon-cloudfront

Using the node module [cloudfront-log-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudfront-log-parser), when doing

```
const CloudFrontParser = require('cloudfront-log-parser');
logstr = "2019-08-29 16:43:02 ATL51-C1 4094 104.129.204.75 GET d2d3d4d5d6.cloudfront.net /static/js/partials/builder-page/builder-page.html 200 https://my.domain.com/ Mozilla/5.0%2520(Macintosh;%2520Intel%2520Mac%2520OS%2520X%252010_14_6)%2520AppleWebKit/537.36%2520(KHTML,%2520like%2520Gecko)%2520Chrome/76.0.3809.100%2520Safari/537.36 - - Miss EYtgWNYeLi6uBaTtmdNzKICvvsfcjVWEBOrFDXrGgs7XS12IuqNd7Q== my.domain.com https 559 0.046 - TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 Miss HTTP/2.0 - -"

let parsed = CloudFrontParser.parse(logstr, { format: 'web' });
```

I get simply

```
[
  {
    date: '2019-08-29 16:43:02 ATL51-C1 4094 104.129.204.75 GET ' +
      'd2d3d4d5d6.cloudfront.net ' +
      '/static/js/partials/builder-page/builder-page.html 200 ' +
      'https://my.domain.com/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel ' +
      'Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' +
      'Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36 - - Miss ' +
      'EYtgWNYeLi6uBaTtmdNzKICvvsfcjVWEBOrFDXrGgs7XS12IuqNd7Q== ' +
      'my.domain.com https 559 0.046 - TLSv1.2 ' +
      'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 Miss HTTP/2.0 - -'
  }
]
```

Which is not a parsed object...

What are we doing wrong?